# ChartJS creating var takes each character and outputs undefined

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, chart.js

I am creating a simple bar chart for my work. I use Python and Pandas for the same. Since I need this for HTML, I am using ChartJS. Below is my piece of code:

```
success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var n = [];
        var s = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            n.push(data[i].name);
            s.push(data[i].score);
        }
```

My data is as below and correctly renders in the console log:

```
[{"name":"ajay","score":"80"},{"name":"smitha","score":"90"},{"name":"ravi","score":"95"}]
```

Now, when I run the for loop above, it picks up each character from the data and outputs it as undefined in the labels. My question is, why isn't it actually picking up the name and score data, for example, ajay and 80 for inputting in variables n and s?

I would really appreciate your response if you help me in understanding the root cause. Why is it not reading the entire name, ajay, and instead throwing 90 undefined labels (90 characters in total)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your response data is a string and a for..in over a string iterates the characters in the string.
If you're expecting your json to be parsed into an array, you have to set the dataType in your ajax request to `json`, use JSON.parse or set the content type on your server to `application/json`.

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var n = [];
        var s = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            n.push(data[i].name);
            s.push(data[i].score);
        }
```

Comment: That worked!! I did understand the string portion of your solution but didn't realize that the data is JSON. Thank you!